# ExtJS - Is it good practice to add all of my application controller inside controller array in Application file

Tags: extjs5

I am using ExtJS 5 to create an big application.
I am trying to minimize the initial load time of the application. Once the application is loaded it is responds very fast.

Inside Application.js file i have declared all the views(>300) inside views[] and all the controllers(>300) inside controllers[]

Is it a good practice to declare all the views and the controllers inside Application.js file or it should not be done ?

Other details -

I am already using Sencha Cmd to build my application. 
The size of the app.js after build completion is around 5MB. 
We are also using gzip so that app.js file gets reduce to around 1.2 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reduce the size of the download prior to logon, you can split the app up into multiple pages. The first page could do the login, then redirect to the next page that brings down the rest of the app.

Alternatively - and this is a lot trickier - you can customise the build process to split your app file into multiple files using the `include` and `exclude` arguments to Sencha Cmd. You can then produce a small bundle that starts the app and presents a login dialog. On successful login, you can load the rest of the application bundle using the Ext.Loader.

Don't ask me how to do this, though - the Sencha Cmd tool is more than a little arcane. If you decide to go down this approach, it would be best to contact Sencha's support team.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your guidance.

I will go with approach where i can reduce the size of the download prior to login. For this i will have to do multi page application.

I am giving an attempt to solve this using following link -

https://www.sencha.com/blog/blazingly-fast-load-times-for-apps-built-with-ext-js-and-sencha-touch/

Answer (score 0):

A nice way of separating concerns of interests is [Using ViewControllers in Ext JS 5](https://www.sencha.com/blog/using-viewcontrollers-in-ext-js-5/). 
Your view controllers will only be created if you create the view. This may reduce load times of your application. The provided link gives really good examples on how to use those kind of controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
If I go by this option then i will have to convert all my Controllers to ViewControllers, this change will take lot of efforts and its almost like rewriting the application.

Even if above change is done i think still the app.js file size will be of same(5MB) size.

Is there a ways where i can tell ExtJS to minimize the app.js file and load the first screen(login view) immediately. By this approach even if the file size is much in size, my initial view(login view) will load instantly.